# BufferedReader Looping Incorrectly

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I know that this is probably something simple, however I cannot seem to find what I have done wrong.

I am comparing output from a webpage to the contents of a text file. I have the following code and it appears that for every result from the webpage the bufferedreader loops through one time. This will be less confusing once I post the code and the results.

**Code**

```
String docOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docThree = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docFour = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docFive = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docSix = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docSeven = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docEight = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[8]/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();
String docNine = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/h5")).getAttribute("textContent").toString();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/CDWProductionDomainsRequiredDocs.txt"))) {
    String sCurrentLine;


    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docOne + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docTwo + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docThree + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docFour + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docFive + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docSix + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docSeven + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docEight + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("Webpage: " + docNine + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**Results**

```
Webpage: Research Request Memo (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: Sample Informed Consent and HIPAA Authorization (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: Research and Development (RD) Committee Approval Letter (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: Data Use Agreement (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: IRB Approval of Waiver of HIPAA-Compliant Authorization (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: Research Protocol (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: CDW-Domain Checklist (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: VA Form 9957 (File Document) Required Doc: Research Request Memo (File Document)
Webpage: Research Request Memo (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: Sample Informed Consent and HIPAA Authorization (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: Research and Development (RD) Committee Approval Letter (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: Data Use Agreement (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: IRB Approval of Waiver of HIPAA-Compliant Authorization (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: Research Protocol (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: CDW-Domain Checklist (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
Webpage: VA Form 9957 (File Document) Required Doc: Research Study Institutional Review Board (IRB) Approval Letter (File Document)
```

**And So On Through The Rest of the File**

So just wondering what noob thing I did, and how I can fix it so it only goes through the file one time and everything matches up to what is coming from the web page?

Comment: You don't need a call to `br.close()` at the end of the `try` block, as you are using try-with-resources (passing an argument to the `try` statement), which closes `br` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes through every webpage from docOne to docNine for each line in your text file. I.e. it compares all nine files to line 1, then to line 2, etc.

Since you have pasted the first 2 lines you read from the text file, and they match the first 2 Webpages, I assume what you want is to read each line once and compare it to one webpage only. What you need to do then is simply lose the while loop and call readline after displaying each result:

```
    sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Webpage: " + docOne + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
    sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Webpage: " + docTwo + " Required Doc: " + sCurrentLine);
```

However that would make your code even harder to read than it already is. You should consider using a Collection (or even an array) instead.

[EDIT] As per gparyani's suggestion, you do not need to call `br.close()` explicitly. Details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: He's using try-with-resources, new in Java 7, and that automatically calls `close()`, so there is no need to put an explicit call to `close()`. (In older versions before try-with-resources, you needed to call it explicitly, but now you don't.)

Comment: @gparyani Thanks, I hadn't seen that. Good to know.